# React js - How to get Click event values from child component to parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, dom-events

Consider I have a Class name User and in that I am rendering child component name 'Games'. So I am passing an event on game component list item which is click event. I want to get values in my User component. So is it possible?

```js
const { Component } = React;

class User extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.onGameItemClick = this.onGameItemClick.bind(this);
    }
    
    onGameItemClick(e) {
        // i want to get here val1 and val2
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Games 
                onGameItemClick = {this.onGameItemClick}
            />            
        )
    }
}

class Games extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                <li onClick={this.props.onGameItemClick} val1="one" val2="two">1</li>
                <li onClick={this.props.onGameItemClick} val1="one" val2="two">2</li>
                <li onClick={this.props.onGameItemClick} val1="one" val2="two">3</li>
            </ul>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <User />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

This way does not work. Since I'm not getting anything in event. So is there any other way to work around this or this is not possible?

Comment: Yes it's obviously possible in react using callbacks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have functions on your `li`s that pass the value to the click handler, rather than putting invalid properties/attributes on `li`s.

See the changes in `Games#render` and `onGameItemClick`:

```js
const { Component } = React;

class User extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.onGameItemClick = this.onGameItemClick.bind(this);
    }
    
    onGameItemClick(e, val1, val2) {
        console.log("val1 =", val1, "val2 =", val2);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Games 
                onGameItemClick = {this.onGameItemClick}
            />            
        )
    }
}

class Games extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                <li onClick={e => this.props.onGameItemClick(e, "val1(1)", "val2(1)")}>1</li>
                <li onClick={e => this.props.onGameItemClick(e, "val1(2)", "val2(2)")}>2</li>
                <li onClick={e => this.props.onGameItemClick(e, "val1(3)", "val2(3)")}>3</li>
            </ul>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <User />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Of course, you'd probably have some list of objects that the `li`s represent, and get the values from that list:

```js
const { Component } = React;

class User extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.onGameItemClick = this.onGameItemClick.bind(this);
    }
    
    onGameItemClick(e, val1, val2) {
        console.log("val1 =", val1, "val2 =", val2);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Games 
                onGameItemClick = {this.onGameItemClick}
            />            
        )
    }
}

class Games extends Component {
    constructor(...args) {
      super(...args);
      this.state = {
          items: [
              {text: "1", val1: "val1(1)", val2: "val2(1)"},
              {text: "2", val1: "val1(2)", val2: "val2(2)"},
              {text: "3", val1: "val1(3)", val2: "val2(3)"}
          ]
      };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <ul>{
                this.state.items.map(obj =>
                    <li onClick={e => this.props.onGameItemClick(e, obj.val1, obj.val2)}>{obj.text}</li>
                )
            }</ul>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <User />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible using callbacks in react. Pass values as params to the prop event handler function

Here is ES6 version of implementation

```
const { Component } = React;

class User extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    onGameItemClick = (e, val1, val2) => {
        // i want to get here val1 and val2
        console.log("values", val1, val2);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Games 
                onGameItemClick = {this.onGameItemClick}
            />            
        )
    }
}

class Games extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                <li onClick={e => this.props.onGameItemClick(e, "one", "two")}>1</li>
                <li onClick={e => this.props.onGameItemClick(e, "three", "four")}>2</li>
                <li onClick={e => this.props.onGameItemClick(e, "five", "six")}>3</li>
            </ul>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <User />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the val1 and val2 as params in this.props.onGameItemClick.

Example:

```
this.props.onGameItemClick(val1,val2)
```

And get this value in parent class as

```
onGameItemClick(val1,val2) {
    // you will  get here val1 and val2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass event from that click handler(native one) and capture it in parent component.

On click event, you'll get an `event` which is native event handler object and that is the one you would be looking for

Parent Component (User.js)

```
import React from "react";
import Games from "./games";

class User extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.onGameItemClick = this.onGameItemClick.bind(this);
  }
  onGameItemClick(e, val) {
    // i want to get here val1 and val2
    console.log("e", e.target.value, val);
  }

  render() {
    return <Games onGameItemClick={this.onGameItemClick} />;
  }
}

export default User;
```

Child Component (games.js)

```
import React from "react";

class Games extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        <li
          onClick={e => this.props.onGameItemClick(e, "val1")}
          val1="one"
          val2="two"
        >
          1
        </li>
        <li
          onClick={e => this.props.onGameItemClick(e, "val2")}
          val1="one"
          val2="two"
        >
          2
        </li>
        <li
          onClick={e => this.props.onGameItemClick(e, "val3")}
          val1="one"
          val2="two"
        >
          3
        </li>
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default Games;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can pass a reference of a method to the child component and call it when the value in child changes.

Here I've made some changes in your code and acchieved what you supposed to do.

```
import React from 'react';

export default class User extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.onGameItemClick = this.onGameItemClick.bind(this);
  }
  onGameItemClick(e, v1, v2) {
    console.log(v1, v2);
    // you also get the event in this function scope
  }

  render() {
    return <Games onGameItemClick={this.onGameItemClick} />;
  }
}

// Games.js file
class Games extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        <li
          onClick={(e) => this.props.onGameItemClick(e,'one', 1)}
          val1="one"
          val2="two"
        >
          1
        </li>
        <li
          onClick={(e) => this.props.onGameItemClick(e, 'two', 2)}
        >
          2
        </li>
        <li
          onClick={(e) => this.props.onGameItemClick(e, 'three', 3)}
          val1="one"
          val2="two"
        >
          3
        </li>
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

**Explanation**:

We are using ES6 Arrow function to send back the event and parameters to the parent component.